# Changing Optimizer results in "Not found in checkpoint" errors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I've trained a MobilenetV1 model using `rmsprop` optimizer for certain number of steps. And now I would like to switch the optimizer from `rmsprop` to `adam` and resume the training from here on. But when it's loading the trained model I get the following errors when I change the optimizer from `rmsprop` to `adam`. I'm using TF-slim for training the model.

```
2017-11-08 12:02:55.104019: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:55.573251: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not
found: Key MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:55.574865: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.043749: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.045234: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.046297: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.047492: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.048571: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.050291: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.050441: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.050613: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.052709: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.053678: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.054344: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.057392: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.058328: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.059245: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
beta2_power not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.059316: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.060721: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.060725: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.060772: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.061939: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.063585: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.064453: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.064561: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.065362: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.065617: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.065991: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.066388: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.066636: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.071692: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_11_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.074423: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_10_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.074599: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.093603: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.101253: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.101527: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.102623: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.102796: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.104507: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.107026: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.107094: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.109413: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.110115: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.110336: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.112213: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.130614: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.130897: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.136210: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.142911: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.142979: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.143942: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.145029: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.151465: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.155150: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.158805: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.160840: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
beta1_power not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.161308: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.161923: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.162912: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.164919: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.165276: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.166302: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.166327: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.168597: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.168642: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.170778: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.171603: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.171758: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.171917: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.172088: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.173677: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.176383: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.176482: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.176577: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.177585: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.180751: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.183693: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.186271: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.193268: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.193934: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.194045: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.195357: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.195555: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.197646: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.197862: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.197918: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.200354: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.201840: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.202547: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.205285: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.207759: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.210149: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_2_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.211509: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.211621: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.222947: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.223892: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.224229: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.228634: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.228725: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.232910: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.232946: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.233005: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.235281: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.237324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.237430: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.240165: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.240403: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.242228: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.254885: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.255150: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.255345: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.255350: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.258022: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.258183: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.258294: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.259887: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.259985: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.261735: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_4_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.261787: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.263350: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.263924: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266010: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266205: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266461: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266500: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266656: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.266831: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.272471: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.272585: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.272833: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.273087: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.276749: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.277123: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.277264: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.277311: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.277774: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_5_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.278007: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.289477: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.289757: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.289982: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.290007: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.290150: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.292335: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.302872: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.302919: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.306711: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.309400: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.310578: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.310677: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.310927: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.311997: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.312181: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_depthwise/depthwise_weights/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.312690: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.313606: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/biases/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.313868: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_7_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.314337: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_pointwise/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.314373: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.315263: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.317037: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.317143: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/biases/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.317737: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.317806: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.317970: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_8_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
2017-11-08 12:02:56.319557: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key
MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint [[Node:
save/RestoreV2_10 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_10/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_10/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Could anyone please help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this issue is different optimizer introduces different sets of extra variables, and these extra variables are also saved in the Checkpoint file. You can solve this issue by explicitly specifying the variables (model itself, not including optimizer-introduced ones) to restore, like the following way:

```
variables_to_restore_full = slim.get_variables_to_restore(include=["resnet_v2"])
variables_to_restore = []

for var in variables_to_restore_full:
    #if 'Momentum' in var.name:
    if 'Adam' in var.name:
       continue
    variables_to_restore.append(var)

self.restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
self.restorer.restore(self.sess, '/PATH/TO/Checkpoint')
```

Comment: Can you explain what causes OP's error?  "The cause of this issue is different optimizer introduces different sets of extra variables, and these extra variables are also saved in the Checkpoint file." doesn't explain why a problem arises. If the ADAM optimizer introduces extra variables, but the variables are still saved, why is an error generated when trying to restore the variables?

Comment: Can you explain what this `slim` is?