# Change optimizer for pre-trained inception v3

Tags: python, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I was wondering how I can change the optimizer for inception v3 from SGD to Adam Optimizer. I would like to keep the weights in pre-trained, but not the default SGD Optimizer. If I add Adam optimizer, it will throw an error saying it cannot find Adam optimizer in pre-trained checkpoint file:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key OptimizeLoss/InceptionV3/Mixed_6b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0d_7x1/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_525 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save_1/Const_0_0, save_1/RestoreV2_525/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_525/shape_and_slices)]]
         [[Node: save_1/Assign_758/_1522 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3805_save_1/Assign_758", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Training only the top layer of the neural network without training inception works fine.
Below is the code used to implement inception v3 (from im2xt):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib.slim.python.slim.nets.inception_v3 import inception_v3_base

slim = tf.contrib.slim


def inception_v3(images,
                 trainable=True,
                 is_training=True,
                 weight_decay=0.00004,
                 stddev=0.1,
                 dropout_keep_prob=0.8,
                 use_batch_norm=True,
                 batch_norm_params=None,
                 add_summaries=True,
                 scope="InceptionV3"):
  """Builds an Inception V3 subgraph for image embeddings.

  Args:
    images: A float32 Tensor of shape [batch, height, width, channels].
    trainable: Whether the inception submodel should be trainable or not.
    is_training: Boolean indicating training mode or not.
    weight_decay: Coefficient for weight regularization.
    stddev: The standard deviation of the trunctated normal weight initializer.
    dropout_keep_prob: Dropout keep probability.
    use_batch_norm: Whether to use batch normalization.
    batch_norm_params: Parameters for batch normalization. See
      tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm for details.
    add_summaries: Whether to add activation summaries.
    scope: Optional Variable scope.

  Returns:
    end_points: A dictionary of activations from inception_v3 layers.
  """
  # Only consider the inception model to be in training mode if it's trainable.
  is_inception_model_training = trainable and is_training

  if use_batch_norm:
    # Default parameters for batch normalization.
    if not batch_norm_params:
      batch_norm_params = {
          "is_training": is_inception_model_training,
          "trainable": trainable,
          # Decay for the moving averages.
          "decay": 0.9997,
          # Epsilon to prevent 0s in variance.
          "epsilon": 0.001,
          # Collection containing the moving mean and moving variance.
          "variables_collections": {
              "beta": None,
              "gamma": None,
              "moving_mean": ["moving_vars"],
              "moving_variance": ["moving_vars"],
          }
      }
  else:
    batch_norm_params = None

  if trainable:
    weights_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)
  else:
    weights_regularizer = None

  with tf.variable_scope(scope, "InceptionV3", [images]) as scope:
    with slim.arg_scope(
        [slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
        weights_regularizer=weights_regularizer,
        trainable=trainable):
      with slim.arg_scope(
          [slim.conv2d],
          weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev),
          activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
          normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
          normalizer_params=batch_norm_params):
        net, end_points = inception_v3_base(images, scope=scope)
        with tf.variable_scope("logits"):
          shape = net.get_shape()
          net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, shape[1:3], padding="VALID", scope="pool")
          net = slim.dropout(
              net,
              keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob,
              is_training=is_inception_model_training,
              scope="dropout")
          net = slim.flatten(net, scope="flatten")

  # Add summaries.
  if add_summaries:
    for v in end_points.values():
      tf.contrib.layers.summaries.summarize_activation(v)

  return net
```

Below is the code used to train the model:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  assert INPUT_FILE_PATTERN, "--input_file_pattern is required"
  assert TRAIN_DIR, "--train_dir is required"

  model_config = configuration.ModelConfig()
  model_config.input_file_pattern = INPUT_FILE_PATTERN
  model_config.inception_checkpoint_file = FLAGS.inception_checkpoint_file
  model_config.train_inception = FLAGS.fine_tune

  training_config = configuration.TrainingConfig()
  model_config.pos_weight = training_config.pos_weight
  model_config.negatives = training_config.negatives
  model_config.class_weights = calculate_class_weights(
    VOCAB_FILEPATH, 
    model_config.vocab_size, 
    use_class_weights=FLAGS.use_class_weights,
    min_class_weight=training_config.min_class_weight
  )

  # Create training directory.
  train_dir = TRAIN_DIR
  if not tf.gfile.IsDirectory(train_dir):
    tf.logging.info("Creating training directory: %s", train_dir)
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(train_dir)

  # Build the TensorFlow graph.
  g = tf.Graph()
  with g.as_default():
    # Build the model.
    model = filter_inception_model.FilterInceptionModel(
        model_config, mode="train")
    model.build()

    # Set up the learning rate.
    learning_rate_decay_fn = None
    learning_rate = tf.constant(training_config.learning_rate)
    if training_config.learning_rate_decay_factor > 0:
      num_batches_per_epoch = (training_config.num_examples_per_epoch /
                               model_config.batch_size)
      decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch *
                        training_config.num_epochs_per_decay)

      def _learning_rate_decay_fn(learning_rate, global_step):
        return tf.train.exponential_decay(
            learning_rate,
            global_step,
            decay_steps=decay_steps,
            decay_rate=training_config.learning_rate_decay_factor,
            staircase=True)

      learning_rate_decay_fn = _learning_rate_decay_fn

    # Set up the training ops.
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=model.total_loss,
        global_step=model.global_step,
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        optimizer=training_config.optimizer,
        clip_gradients=training_config.clip_gradients,
        learning_rate_decay_fn=learning_rate_decay_fn,
        summaries=["gradients"]
    )

    # Set up the Saver for saving and restoring model checkpoints.
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=training_config.max_checkpoints_to_keep)

  # Run training.
  steps = round((FLAGS.number_of_epochs*
    training_config.num_examples_per_epoch)/model_config.batch_size)
  steps = int(steps)
  print("Total number of steps to process: %d" % steps)
  if steps != 0:
    tf.contrib.slim.learning.train(
      train_op,
      train_dir,
      log_every_n_steps=FLAGS.log_every_n_steps,
      graph=g,
      global_step=model.global_step,
      save_summaries_secs=1800,
      number_of_steps=steps,
      init_fn=model.init_fn,
      saver=saver,
      #session_wrapper=tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession
    )
```

I would appreciate any insights into this

EDIT: Add error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194449/changing-optimizer-results-in-not-found-in-checkpoint-errors

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for this?